# Socket does not work properly after deployment

Tags: reactjs, webrtc, p2p, simple-peer

I used simple Peer and react for peer-to-peer connection.
And I made and distributed a video chat app that other people can participate in, and now it works in the local environment, but it doesn't work at all in the distributed environment.
A first-time visitor does not recognize that a new person has arrived.
The second person who entered has two faces

I don't know what's wrong with this part.
please help me..

client

```
const Video = (props) => {
  const anotherUserRef = useRef(null);
  console.log(props, "props");
  useEffect(() => {
    props.peer.on("stream", (stream) => {
      console.log("stream", stream);
      anotherUserRef.current.srcObject = stream;
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Webcam
        className="anotherUser"
        playsInline
        autoPlay
        ref={anotherUserRef}
      />
    </>
  );
};


...

  useEffect(() => {
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({
        video: videoConstraints,
        audio: true,
      })
      .then((stream) => {
        const peers = [];
        userVideo.current.srcObject = stream;

        console.log("원래 여기 있떤 사람들", userInfo);
        userInfo.forEach((user) => {
          const peer = createPeer(user, socket.id, stream);

          peersRef.current.push({
            peerID: user,
            peer,
          });
          peers.push(peer);
        });

        setPeers(peers);
        console.log("나 있기전에 있던 사람들", peers);

        socket.on("user joined", (payload) => {
          const peer = addPeer(payload.signal, payload.callerID, stream);
          peersRef.current.push({
            peerID: payload.callerID,
            peer,
          });

          setPeers((users) => [...users, peer]);
        });

        socket.on("receiving-returned-signal", (payload) => {
          console.log("signal돌려받음", payload);
          const item = peersRef.current.find((p) => p.peerID === payload.id);
          item.peer.signal(payload.signal);
        });
      });

    return () => {
      userVideo.current = null;

      socket.off("user joined");
      socket.off(SOCKET.USER);
      socket.off(SOCKET.RECEIVING_RETURNED_SIGNAL);
    };
  }, []);

  function createPeer(userToSignal, callerID, stream) {
    console.log(userToSignal, callerID, stream);
    const peer = new Peer({
      initiator: true,
      trickle: false,
      stream,
    });

    peer.on("signal", (signal) => {
      console.log("this is signal", signal);
      socket.emit("sending signal", {
        userToSignal,
        callerID,
        signal,
      });
    });

    return peer;
  }

  function addPeer(incomingSignal, callerID, stream) {
    const peer = new Peer({
      initiator: false,
      trickle: false,
      stream,
    });

    peer.on("signal", (signal) => {
      console.log(signal, "누가 들어왓대", callerID, "<-얘가 왔대");
      socket.emit("returning signal", { signal, callerID });
    });
    console.log("this is incomingSignal", incomingSignal);
    peer.signal(incomingSignal);

    return peer;
  }

  return (
        <Webcam className="user" ref={userVideo} autoPlay playsInline />
        {peers && peers.map((peer, index) => <Video key={index} peer={peer} />)}
);
```

server

```
 socket.on("sending signal", (payload) => {
      console.log(
        "here is sendingsignal",
        payload.callerID,
        payload.userToSignal,
        "~에게 보냄"
      );

      io.to(payload.userToSignal).emit("user joined", {
        signal: payload.signal,
        callerID: payload.callerID,
      });
    });

    socket.on("returning signal", (payload) => {
      io.to(payload.callerID).emit("receiving-returned-signal", {
        signal: payload.signal,
        id: socket.id,
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If its working fine on local network, it might be failing due to NAT traversal and/or firewalls outside the network. The only way to overcome them is to use STUN/TURN servers. You can specify them in the `config` parameter of your `Peer` object. For example,

```js
const peer = new Peer({
      initiator: false,
      trickle: false,
      config: { iceServers: [{ urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' },{urls: 'stun:global.stun.twilio.com:3478?transport=udp' }]},
      stream,
    });
```

If you're really interested in learning more about these STUN/TURN servers and a list of free STUN/TURN servers, do check out [this section of my blog](https://www.100ms.live/blog/webrtc-python-react-app#stun%2Fturn-server(s)).